# How do I evaluate this Integral?

Tags: density-function, integral

I’m reading Glen Cowan’s book on statistical data analysis and was stuck on an integral that has to do with crv transformations. I’m not able to evaluate the integral

$$
g(a)da = \int_{x(a)}^{x(a)+|\frac{dx}{da}|da}{f(x)dx}
$$

which results in

$$
g(a) = f(x(a))|\frac{dx}{da}|
$$

I’m trying to understand how the PDF g(a) reached that final form. Apologies if the question is formatted incorrectly, this is my first post on the site.

Comment: The result is an approximation: draw a picture of the area in question and approximate it by a rectangle.  Divide by $da$ to solve for $g(a).$